# How to query for records where difference is greater than 5 min with current time - createdAt in postgres using knexjs

Tags: postgresql, knex.js

I'd like to query for all records where the difference between createdAt and the current time is greater than 5 mins.

```
SELECT * FROM Rides where "createdAt" < NOW() - INTERVAL '5 MINUTE';
```

I tried this but got no success.

```
return db('TABLENAME')
  .SELECT('*')
  .where('COL1', 'data1')
  .andWhere('COL2', 'data2')
  .andWhereRaw('createdAt', '<', 'now() - INTERVAL 5 MINUTE');
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will need to use `knex.raw()` to pass something that is not a "user-input".

```
return db('TABLENAME')
  .SELECT('*')
  .where('COL1', 'data1')
  .andWhere('COL2', 'data2')
  .andWhere('createdAt', '<', db.raw(`now() - INTERVAL '5 MINUTE'`));
```

Comment: You need to wrap 5 Minutes with quotes, I've updated my snippet